# SQLDriverConnect hangs when client restricts to TLS 1.2

Tags: c, sql-server, odbc, tls1.2

We have a some legacy code (in C), a Windows service that connects via the {SQL Server} driver to a SQL Server database.  A client that has used it for a number of years has recently decided to restrict the protocols on its server on TLS 1.2.  Now the service will not connect to the database.

Tried changing the {SQL Server} drive to the {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}, and the call to SQLDriverConnect hangs indefinitely.  If anyone could provide any insight, we'd be eternally grateful.

```
SQLHENV     hEnv = NULL;
SQLHDBC     hDbc = NULL;
char        inString[512];
char        outString[512];
SQLSMALLINT outLength;

SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &hEnv);
SQLSetEnvAttr(hEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hEnv, &hDbc);

outLength = 512;
memset(outString, 0, 512);
strcpy(inString, "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=MYSERVER\\MYINSTANCE;Database=MYDB;UID=sa;PWD=MYPASSWORD");
SQLDriverConnect(hDbc, NULL, inString, (SQLSMALLINT)strlen(inString), outString, 512, &outLength, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);


SQLDisconnect(hDbc);
SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hDbc);

SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);
```

Comment: Is it related? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d7c99787-ac58-4c20-b899-1790264af676/in-windows-2012sql-2012-odbc-connection-hangs-if-connection-pooling-is-enabled?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: I don't think so.  I checked and connection pooling is off.